# Why does forge.message.broadcast cause `Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.` in Chrome?

Tags: trigger.io

Whenever I use forge.message.broadcast I see a bunch of errors immediately:

`Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

It seems to be related directly to the number of open tabs + the number of open developer consoles. However, there's no stack trace whatsoever, and seems impossible to track down.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, looking at the definition of `forge.message.broadcast`:

```
forge.message.broadcast = function (r, s, t, q) {
    chrome.windows.getAll({
        populate: true
    }, function (u) {
        u.forEach(function (v) {
            v.tabs.forEach(function (x) {
                if (x.url.indexOf("chrome-extension:") != 0) {
                    var w = chrome.tabs.connect(x.id);
                    if (t) {
                        w.onMessage.addListener(function (y) {
                            t(y)
                        })
                    }
                    w.postMessage({
                        type: r,
                        content: s
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    });
    var p = chrome.extension.connect();
    if (t) {
        p.onMessage.addListener(function (u) {
            t(u)
        })
    }
    p.postMessage({
        type: r,
        content: s
    })
}
```

`forge.message.broadcast` will attempt to send a message to each open tab. It only filters out the `chrome-extension` urls, so it will also try to message any open `developer-tools` window. However, If there isn't a listener on the tab, you may receive a "Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." error for each such tab in Chrome - this is expected and fine **if** you don't expect them to be responding to forge.message.broadcast messages.

If you do expect them to respond, you must **first** use `forge.message.listen` in the appropriate tab.